# R: How to Fill Points in ggplot2 with a variable

Tags: r

I am attempting to make a `ggplot2` scatter plot that is grouped by bins in R. I successfully made the first model, which I did not try to alter the fill for. But when I tried to have the fill of the scatter plot be based upon my variable (Miss.) ,which is a numeric value ranging from 0.00 to 0.46, it essentially ignores the heat map scale and turns everything gray.

```
   ggplot(data = RightFB, mapping = aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk))+
   geom_bin_2d(bins = 15)+
   scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")+
   ylim(5, 20)+
   xlim(0,15)+
   coord_fixed(1.3)


   ggplot(data = RightFB, mapping = aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk, fill 
   =Miss.))+
   geom_bin_2d(bins = 15)+
   scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")+
   ylim(5, 20)+
   xlim(0,15)+
   coord_fixed(1.3)
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand your problem, so let's replicate it with a reproducible example. Obviously we don't have your data, but the following data frame has the same names, types and ranges as your own data, so this walk-through should work for you.

```r
set.seed(1)

RightFB <- data.frame(TMHrzBrk = runif(1000, 0, 15),
                      TMIndVertBrk = runif(1000, 5, 20),
                      Miss. = runif(1000, 0, 0.46))
```

Your first plot will look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = RightFB, mapping = aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk)) +
  geom_bin_2d(bins = 15) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  ylim(5, 20) +
  xlim(0, 15) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
#> Warning: Removed 56 rows containing missing values (`geom_tile()`).
```

[image]

Here, the fill colors represent the counts of observations within each bin. But if you try to map the fill to `Miss.`, you get all gray squares:

```r
ggplot(data = RightFB, mapping = aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk,
                                     fill = Miss.)) +
  geom_bin_2d(bins = 15) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  ylim(5, 20) +
  xlim(0, 15) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill
#> i This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> i Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?
#> Removed 56 rows containing missing values (`geom_tile()`).
```

[image]

The reason this happens is that by default `geom_bin_2d` calculates the bins and the counts within each bin to get the fill variable. There are multiple observations within each bin, and they all have a different value of `Miss.` . Furthermore, `geom_bin_2d` doesn't know what you want to do with this variable. My guess is that you are looking for the *average* of `Miss.` within each bin, but this is difficult to achieve within the framework of `geom_bin_2d`.

The alternative is to calculate the bins yourself, get the average of `Miss.` in each bin, and plot as a `geom_tile`

```r
RightFB %>%
  mutate(TMHrzBrk = cut(TMHrzBrk, breaks = seq(0, 15, 1), seq(0.5, 14.5, 1)),
         TMIndVertBrk = cut(TMIndVertBrk, seq(5, 20, 1), seq(5.5, 19.5, 1))) %>%
  group_by(TMHrzBrk, TMIndVertBrk) %>%
  summarize(Miss. = mean(Miss., na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(across(TMHrzBrk:TMIndVertBrk, ~as.numeric(as.character(.x)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk, fill = Miss.)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  ylim(5, 20) +
  xlim(0, 15) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

With the link to the data in the comments, here is a full reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

RightFB <- read.csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rileyfeltner/",
                           "FB-Analysis/main/Right%20FB.csv"))

RightFB <- RightFB[c(2:6, 9, 11, 13, 18, 19)]
RightFB$Miss. <- as.numeric(as.character(RightFB$Miss.))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
RightFB$TMIndVertBrk <- as.numeric(as.character(RightFB$TMIndVertBrk))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
RightFB <- na.omit(RightFB)
RightFB1 <- filter(RightFB, P > 24)

RightFB %>%
  mutate(TMHrzBrk = cut(TMHrzBrk, breaks = seq(0, 15, 1), seq(0.5, 14.5, 1)),
         TMIndVertBrk = cut(TMIndVertBrk, seq(5, 20, 1), seq(5.5, 19.5, 1))) %>%
  group_by(TMHrzBrk, TMIndVertBrk) %>%
  summarize(Miss. = mean(Miss., na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(across(TMHrzBrk:TMIndVertBrk, ~as.numeric(as.character(.x)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TMHrzBrk, y = TMIndVertBrk, fill = Miss.)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  ylim(5, 20) +
  xlim(0, 15) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
#> Warning: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (`geom_tile()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That unfortunately did not work on my end. I am getting an error that argument "by" is missing with no default

Comment: @RileyF the above code is a full reprex. If you copy / paste the code in a clean R session then you will get the same output

Comment: @RileyF whereabouts do you get the error?

Comment: The error is occurring due to the summarize function on my end.

Comment: @RileyF my guess is that this is the wrong `summarize` function. That is the error you get if you have the `Hmisc` package loaded. Could you please try starting a fresh session, loading tidyverse then trying the above code again? Thanks.

Comment: Still is not working for me. Thank you for the help though

Comment: @RileyF if you could post a sample of your data or a link to it, I could show you how to achieve it. As you can see from the above, this code works with my sample data. Perhaps yours is different in some important way? Are you getting a different error now?

Comment: https://github.com/rileyfeltner/FB-Analysis

Comment: Here it is, thank you again for looking at it!

Comment: @RileyF I have posted an update with a reprex which, starting from a brand new R session, with no other packages loaded, will generate your plot.